# Paypal Recurring invoicing for recurring payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to integrate Paypal for recurring payments.PayPal provide an option to do so by creating Recurring Profile for customer.But I like to know is there any option to send recurring invoice to customer.I will implement this in php though API. So need to know does API provide such option.

Comment: Did you read the API documentation?

Comment: Yes I read the documentation.There is an option to create invoice separately. Didn't find an option which will link recurring payment and invoice.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to have PayPal send recurring invoice to your customer. The only way is implement your own recurring system and send invoice using PayPal Invoicing API.

You will find invoice documentation here. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#invoicing